# DAR archive for Mac

Tags: macos, archiving

I need to open an archive that was compressed using the [DAR archiving algorithm](http://dar.linux.free.fr/). I have got 5 DAR volumes here and need to extract them on my Mac.

The link to the Mac binaries is broken on the official website and using Google for DAR is an epic fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the source tarball for DAR at [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dar/files/), or see the [official site for CVS access](http://dar.linux.free.fr/doc/index.html#Downloading).  Make sure you have the [requirements for building DAR from source](http://dar.linux.free.fr/doc/index.html#requirements).

Obviously you'll need a build environment configured on your Mac; take a look at [MacPorts](http://guide.macports.org/).

Comment: if I can find a useful link describing Mac build environments I'll update this post.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about macports, it's kinda like apt on ubuntu which ofcourse is nice. Going to install dar through macports and use commandline like i'm used to :)

Thanks!